# Generate cabal file with dependencies on foreign libs

Tags: haskell, cabal

Is it possible to automatically generate cabal file for a given haskell project, that will create appropriate `Build-depends` dependencies for all the libs that the project uses?

Comment: This could likely be accomplished via a simple script using `ghc-pkg find-module` for most cases.

Answer (score 10):

Yes!  In fact, the 'cabal init' command does this in the HEAD version of cabal-install.  It's true that it's not possible to get it exactly right in all cases, but it just makes the best guesses it can and then lets you fix the generated build-depends list as necessary.

Comment: Ok, not possible in the general case but, like termination, the most general case isn't the concern.  Thanks for pointing this out, I totally forgot how much work `cabal init` did.

Answer (score 3):

No, because some modules are provided by more than one package and it isn't practical (or even possible, really) for cabal to decide which one you want to use.

You can search for which package is provided by which module, or just run cabal-install several times until you've covered all the deps.